# If $p=q$ is this the only case for real?

Tags: differential-geometry

From this:

[image: text]

we can see if $p=q$ then $\lambda^{-p}\bar{\lambda}^{-q}$ is real.

Is this possible for any other combination of $p,q,\lambda$?

(If someone knows a fix to my $\LaTeX$ formatting issue, could you please explain a fix!)

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's just analyze the number $\lambda^{-p} \bar{\lambda}^{-q}$. If $\lambda = \rho e^{i \phi}$, then $\bar{\lambda} = \rho e^{-i \phi}$ and 
$\lambda^{-p} \bar{\lambda}^{-q} = \rho^2 e^{i(q-p)\phi}$. For $\lambda^{-p} \bar{\lambda}^{-q}$ to be real number we need $(q-p) \phi$ to be of form $\pi k, \; k \in \mathbb{Z}$. And if $p \neq q$ then $\phi$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$, i.e. $\phi = \frac{k}{q-p} \pi$. So the answer is "Yes" — there are a lot of other combinations of $p$, $q$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: One concrete example is given by $\lambda = i$, $p = 1$, $q = 3$. Then $\lambda^{-p}\bar{\lambda}^{-q} = i^{-1}(-i)^{-3} = (-i)i^3 = -i^4 = -1$.